# C++: monitor and condition variable interprocesses

Tags: c++, c++11

After studying concurrent programming theory
all a semester long, I wanted to put in practice
what I learnt, overall monitors.
I know that monitors are an object (instance of class) collecting data structs, functions and condition variable. I've seen that in C++ I can
do all this with threads. Instead, what Can I do if I wanted to share a monitor(conditions, data structs...)between processes? Maybe created wth fork()...for example producer and consumer.
I've seen there is a boost library to share condition variables inter processes...is it right?

Answer (score 1):

There are several choices, see *interprocess communication* on major search engines. If you wanna share objects and flags, it sounds that the two processes are working together tightly, in this case threads are better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Interprocess communication is typically done via OS semaphores and shared memory. The framework for allocating and managing these resources is very much OS-dependent.

Fortunately, the Boost C++ library already has an OS-independent abstraction which can do [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to split the problem into 3 or more parts.

An abstract interface for the methods on your monitor.  If the object is supposed to be inter-process, you can either implement the IPC under the hood, or rely on each process having identical code for the methods.

The data can either be stored in one spot (and everyone uses IPC to talk to that one spot), or stored in each process and kept in sync.  Note that a shared memory for the data is one solution for IPC for the data (that allows the code to live locally in each process).

The third part would be synchronization.  This can be handled as a completely different problem than the "common object", and mostly solved orthogonally to how you make it work.

One way to do this is to make a template that synchronizes access to arbitrary data, sort of like this:

```
template<typename T, typename MyMutex=std::mutex, typename MyLock=std::unique_lock>
struct Synced {
  mutable MyMutex mutex;
  T* t;
  Synced( T& t_ ):t(&t_), mutex() {}
  Synced( T& t_, MyMutex&& m ):t(&t_), mutex(std::move(m)) {}
  template<typename Functor>
  auto operator()( Functor&& f )->decltype( f(declval<T>()) ) const {
    MyLock _(mutex);
    return f(*t);
  }
};
```

which is an example of a synchronization wrapper around an arbitrary type T.  Ie:

```
Synced<std::ostream> synced_cout(std::cout);
void test() {
  synced_cout([&](std::ostream& os) {
    os << "Hello world!\n";
  });
}
```

where I have synchronized access to an `ostream` in a generic way.

(Much of the above blatantly stolen from either Bjarne Stroustrup or Herb Stutter, any errors are my own).